# removing look ahead in regex

Tags: regex, r

I am finding sub string in a string repeating thrice consecutively and removing the obtained sub string from it using `gregexpr`. However, in my attempt to find sub strings I need to remove lookahead. For example, consider a string `kajaaaaaaaaaaaa`, here `aaaa` is outputting along with `aaa`, `aa` and `a`. Since the last three are included in `aaaa` how can I get rid of them? I have tried a lot but have been unable to do it. I want to capture a sub string repeating itself consecutively for atleast thrice in a string.

```
s <- 'kajaaaaaaaaaaaa'
m <- gregexpr(sprintf'(?=(.{2,})\\1{2,})',t) s, perl=TRUE)

unique(mapply(function(x, y) substr(s, x, x+y-1), 
              attr(m[[1]], 'capture.start'), 
              attr(m[[1]], 'capture.length')))
```

Comment: Could you post the regular expression you're using?

Comment: it's so hard to understand your needs. What's your expected ouptut? Could you post some more examples?

Comment: `removing look ahead in regex` - are you parsing a regular expression ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have put the code.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: 'aaaa' only since, rest are included in it.

Comment: did you mean this https://regex101.com/r/eC3dN2/1?

Comment: how can i modify the above code? Don't see the removing part right now. Also, sub string must repeat given t number of times consecutively.

Comment: Your code doesn't run.

Comment: This `(.{2,})` captures 3 characters, any characters. What  exactly do you want to do with it ? This `(.(.(.)))` captures 3 characters progressively that can be back referenced. What exactly do you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your regex correctly:

`m <- gregexpr('(.)(?=(\1{3}))', s, perl=TRUE)`

which will match anything repeating three times after the original

The result will be two match groups one for a and one for "aaa" use the latter, as you have to still have a match group to find repeats

Comment: `s <- '111111111111'
> 
> thr <- 3
> 
> m <- gregexpr('(.)(?=\1{3})', s, perl=TRUE)
> 
> a = unique(mapply(function(x, y) substr(s, x, x+y-1), 
+               attr(m[[1]], 'capture.start'), 
+               attr(m[[1]], 'capture.length'))); a[nchar(a)==max(nchar(a))]`              Null output its showing.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to remove lookahead.

Just omit it, lookahead is not needed here:

```
> gregexpr('(..+)\\1{2,}', s, perl=TRUE) -> m
> mapply(function(x, y) substr(s, x, x+y-1), attr(m[[1]], 'capture.start')
+                                          , attr(m[[1]], 'capture.length'))
[1] "aaaa"
```